# how to access facebook or twitter using blackberry API?

Tags: facebook, networking, blackberry, twitter, social-networking

I am newbie for such kind of social networking Application integration using blackberry API.

i want to develope such kind of application which can use the facebook or twitter social networking site integration using available blackberry api.

how to access the faceBook using blackberry API?
Is there any webservice available of facebook on which blackberry api can work and access it?
is there any application exist with whole source code for accessing the facebook using the blackberry api?

if anybody has any solution or any useful link or any code snippet,which would be appreciated.:)

Thanks,
Mishal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Facebook offers a webservice-based API that you can use - they provide information about it here:

[http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Platform_Basics](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

I would strongly recommend using the Sun Java Wireless Toolkit (Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2_01 for CLDC available here: [SJW Toolkit](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/)) - use the Utilities application when installed and then the "Stub Generator" - it will create J2ME classes and stubs for all web service calls that you can then bring into your BlackBerry project. I have used this without fail to call web services from the BlackBerry and it is much easier than creating your own web service call wrappers. Everything will be strong typed and any required objects and classes will all be created for you.

Answer (score 7):

### BlackBerry FaceBook Connect

See code sample provided by [Eki Y. Baskoro: Facebook Connect on Blackberry](http://www.baskoro.web.id/facebook-connect-blackberry-HOWTO.html)

> The following is a short HOWTO on using Facebook Connect on Blackberry. I created a simple Facade encapsulating the Facebook REST API as well as added 'rough' MVC approach for screen navigation. I have tested on JDE 4.5 using 8320 simulator. This is still work in progress and all work is GPLed.

### BlackBerry Twitter Connect

And talking about [twitter](http://twitter.com), there is a [twitter api](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Things-Every-Developer-Should-Know) and opensource j2me client - [jibjib](http://code.google.com/p/jibjib/) to look at.
Sample to post status:

```java
 class Scr extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {
    BasicEditField musername;
    BasicEditField mPassword;
    BasicEditField mStatus;
    ButtonField mUpdateStatus;

    public Scr() {
        add(musername = new BasicEditField("username: ", ""));
        add(mPassword = new BasicEditField("password: ", ""));
        add(mStatus = new BasicEditField("status: ", ""));
        mUpdateStatus = new ButtonField(ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
        mUpdateStatus.setLabel("update status");
        mUpdateStatus.setChangeListener(this);
        add(mUpdateStatus);
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if (mUpdateStatus == field) {
            String username = musername.getText().trim();
            String password = mPassword.getText().trim();
            String status = mStatus.getText().trim();
            updateStatus(username, password, status);
        } else {

        }
    }

    void updateStatus(String username, String password, String status) {
        String response = "";
        try {
            String query = "status=" + urlEncode(status);
            String len = String.valueOf(query.length());
            SocketConnection hc = (SocketConnection) Connector
                    .open("socket://twitter.com:80");
            DataOutputStream dout = 
                new DataOutputStream(hc.openOutputStream());
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(hc.openInputStream());
            String userPass = username + ":" + password;
            byte[] encoded = Base64OutputStream.encode(userPass.getBytes(), 0,
                    userPass.length(), false, false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            String request = "POST /statuses/update.json HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                    + "Host: twitter.com:80\r\n"
                    + "User-Agent: curl/7.18.0 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) " +
                            "libcurl/7.18.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3.3 " +
                            "libidn/1.1\r\n"
                    + "Accept: */*\r\n"
                    + "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                    + "Content-Length: " + len + "\r\nAuthorization: Basic "
                    + new String(encoded) + "\r\n\r\n";
            bos.write(request.getBytes());
            bos.write(query.getBytes());
            dout.write(bos.toByteArray());
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
            byte[] bs = new byte[900];
            din.readFully(bs);
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bos.write(bs);
            din.close();
            hc.close();
            response = bos.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage()+" "+response);
        }
    }

    public static String urlEncode(String s) {
        if (s != null) {
            try {
                s = new String(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            }
            StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                    int b = (int) s.charAt(i);
                    if ((b >= 0x30 && b <= 0x39) || (b >= 0x41 && b <= 0x5A)
                            || (b >= 0x61 && b <= 0x7A)) {
                        tmp.append((char) b);
                    } else if (b == 0x20) {
                        tmp.append("+");
                    } else {
                        tmp.append("%");
                        if (b <= 0xf) {
                            tmp.append("0");
                        }
                        tmp.append(Integer.toHexString(b));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return tmp.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

**Twitter API ME lib v.1.8 for RIM** is available on [Project Kenai](http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/downloads/directory/1.8)

Comment: FaceBook jar is available for 5.0 Os and above,in http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/

Comment: I am working with the facebook api... I used the sample code snippets in the readme file to publishstatus but the status is not publishing and it is not giving any exception. Note that I have already created an app on fb and used the appropriate credentials.. Not working for me either, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Twitter Basic Auth method is deprecated starting today.
You must now use OAuth ...

Answer (score 0):

for connecting to Facebook from blackberry using native apps you can use Facebook sdk for blackberry. you can download from github.com. search for Facebook sdk. it will also comes with some samples which clearly demonstrates the usage of Facebook api.

Comment: I am working with the facebook api... I used the sample code snippets in the readme file to publishstatus but the status is not publishing and it is not giving any exception. Note that I have already created an app on fb and used the appropriate credentials..