# Twitter APIs for blackberry implementation

Tags: blackberry, twitter, external, jar

I am trying to implement the blackberry application which will help the user to update his status through application.

Its like user will enter the username, password and status it will update his status on twitter.

I have seen Twitter API docs but didnt understood how to start. It has many things like application registration and OAuth process which i felt very ambiguity.

I have also tried to use some external jar for blackberry but some of its classes/packages is not supported

```
twitter4j-core-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ----> Error preverifying class twitter4j.TwitterBase
    java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/io/Serializable

jtwitter.jar ---> VERIFIER ERROR org/json/Test.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V:
Cannot find class java/io/StringWriter

signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar ---> Error preverifying class oauth.signpost.http.HttpParameters
    java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Map
```

Please friends help me with how to start. it will be appreciated if any link or jar which support on blackberry can shared.

Comment: seems to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340196/how-to-access-facebook-or-twitter-using-blackberry-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a 10,000 mile view, you first need to preverify your jar files using the preverify.exe tool in the bin directory of your simulator.

You then need to create a new project, change the project type from CDLC -> Library and add your twitter4j-*.jar to it. Set this project as a reference (right click your main project and it's somewhere in the properties) to your main project. Next, configure build path for the main project and add twitter4j-* to your build path.

A detailed view with screenshots for eclipse is provided for a different library at -
http://www.craigagreen.com/index.php?/Blog/blackberry-and-net-webservice-tutorial-part-1.html

More info - 
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Tutorial-How-To-Use-3rd-Party-Libraries-in-your-Applications/m-p/177543

If it's a simple tweet, you might be better of just doing a HTTP POST with the appropriate parameters.

Check `URLEncodedPostData` and `HTTPConnection` for more info about HTTP Post requests.

Comment: your given link is not working...

http://www.craigagreen.com/index.php?/Blog/blackberry-and-net-webservice-tutorial-part-1.html