# Mobile phones that can support facebook apps

Tags: facebook, mobile

Does anyone know of a good website that I can check to find out what are the mobile phones (smartphones) that support facebook apps (Facebook API calls and all that)?

I am pretty sure that all smartphones have facebook support except for blackberries, but I would still like to find a full list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blackberry currently has it in their AppWorld http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/680?lang=en

Nokia currently has it in their Ovi Store http://store.ovi.com/search?q=facebook

Saying that I don't believe there is a current "smart" phone that doesn't have a facebook app.  I didn't link it, but Palm/HP WebOS also has a facebook app.

To also answer the API question I saw 3rd party apps on all platforms as well so I don't believe there is a current app market/platform that doesn't support the FB API.

Answer (score 0):

It would be based more on OS. iOS, Android, and Windows 7 all support the calls. According to this SO [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340196/how-to-access-facebook-or-twitter-using-blackberry-api), Blackberry works too.

There is also the [Facebook Blackberry SDK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/)

Comment: Yea I looked at that earlier. Apparently it only works for platforms above v5, and facebook has upgraded to v4.5. Thanks though